# Consistency for a set of formula (first order logic), with resolution technique.

Tags: logic

$\neg P(x,y)\vee P(S,y)$ (1)

$\neg P(x,f(x))\vee P(S,f(x))$ (2)

$\neg P(S,f(x))\vee P(x,f(x))$ (3)

Is, this set of formulas, consistent? I think so, because I could not to obtain a contradiction. What do you think?

Comment: Usually to speak of consistency of a set of sentences of first order logic. The above looks like they are missing some quantifiers. You should also clarify what is the first order language you are working in.

Comment: sorry, each variable x y is to be understood universally quantified.

Comment: What about $S$? Is it also a variable?

Comment: S ground, constant.

Comment: And what about $\rceil$?

Comment: "$\vee$= or", "$\rceil$=not". Sorry again all for my inaccuracy.

Comment: The symbol you used, $\rceil$ (produced using `\rceil`), is meant to be used as the right-hand element of the ceiling function $\lceil\cdot\rceil$. The symbol intended for use as a negation symbol is $\neg$ (produced using `\neg`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P$ is interpreted to always be true, then (no matter how $S$ and $f$ are interpreted), all three sentences are true. Thus the set has a model and hence is consistent.